# Prevent component reload on Context change (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a component that imports and uses CONTEXT. In this component, I render data from the CONTEXT based on link props. Until this moment everything is fine, but in the same component, I need to have an ability to update CONTEXT which means delete data I actually use in that component. That causes of course error, because the component is refreshing because of CONTEXT change.

Does anyone have an idea of how to prevent component reload on CONTEXT change?

```js
...other imports...
import AllWarriorsContext from '../../contexts/AllWariorsContext';


export default function WarriorPage() {
    let { identy } = useParams(); 
    const [myWarriorsListContext, setMyWarriorsListContext] = useContext(AllWarriorsContext);
    const {number} = myWarriorsListContext.find((e) => e.number === identy)); //destructuring from one of the context object

const deleteMe = () => {
    setMyWarriorsListContext((myWarriorsListContext) => {
            return myWarriorsListContext.filter((e) => {
                return e.number !== identy;
            });
        });
}

    return(
        <>
            <button
                onClick={deleteMe} // after click of course i got an error
            >
                 delete
            </button>
        </>
    );

}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: 'can't descructure from null'

Comment: Strange error, are you sure that is the error you copied and pasted from the console?

Comment: Please add the code providing the context value

Comment: When a component has subscribed to a state with context, you cannot prevent it from rerendering, because thats the point of having state on that component. If you only want to set state from your component without subscribing to it with useContext, you have to use other state management tools, since Context is used with useContext in functional components. You could use a parent component that handles that or you can use a React state management library like rx-global, which is less than 50kb and allows you to do anything with your state with minimal syntaxt